# Version conflict django-oauth-toolkit>0.12.0 and idna==3.1

Tags: python, django, conflict, django-oauth-toolkit

Why I have a problem with updating Django from version 1.11.29 to 2.0.13. When updating the library `django-oauth-toolkit` to version 1.2.0 - version support Django 2.0, I receive this error:

```
__version__ = pkg_resources.require("django-oauth-toolkit")[0].version
 needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (idna 3.1 (/.virtualenvs/django-oauth-tookit-conflict/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('idna<2.8,>=2.5'), {'requests'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need update request library to version 2.23.0.
And install idna==2.10